# Error inserting in mysql (constraint)

Tags: mysql, constraints

when I try to insert in the database I get the following error:

```
DBD::mysql::st execute failed: Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails (`vym`.`vendedor`, CONSTRAINT `fk_vendedor_division` FOREIGN KEY (`codigo_empresa`, `codigo_division`) REFERENCES `division` (`codigo_empresa`, `codigo`)) at vendedores_aes_insert_85 line 53
```

I know I have a constraint but I don't know how to interpret the message. What is the constraint and why?

Comment: [constraint](http://www.w3resource.com/mysql/creating-table-advance/constraint.php)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like the `division` column is violating it. I would check the definition of the `` `fk_vendedor_division `` constraint.

Basically, the error is saying that you are trying to use a division in the `vendedor` table that doesnt exist in the other one.

Answer (score 1):

The constraint is *the foreign key* on table `vym.vendedor`; columns `codigo_empresa`, `codigo_division`) are referencing table `division` columns (`codigo_empresa`, `codigo`).